# Deleting objects from template list

Tags: c++, stl, subclass, destructor, delete-operator

I have a template list say,

```
List<SuperClass*>* mList;

for(int i = 0;i < mList->ElementsCount();i++)
    mList->DeleteElementAtIndex(i);
```

in mList objects of subclasses are added.

While on deleting object from the list, 
should I need to convert the object into corresponding subclasses and call the delete method?

Comment: You have a lot less to worry about if you replace containers of native pointers with containers of smart pointers (like `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<SuperClass> >`) or dedicated pointer containers (like `boost::ptr_vector<SuperClass>`).

Comment: Still, keep in mind that they too need a virtual destructor to work correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, calling the `delete` operator on each pointer without explicit conversion is enough, but you must make sure that the destructors of the classes in the class hierarchy are declared as `virtual` (it's enough to mark just the one of the base class as such). In this way, the call to the destructor will be a virtual call, so the correct destructor will be called.

If you don't declare the destructor as virtual, when calling `delete` on each pointer the destructor of the base class will be called instead of the correct one; this is the motivation why it's considered almost always an error to have class hierarchies without a `virtual` destructor.

More info about this can be found in the [relevant entry](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7) of the C++ FAQ Lite.

By the way, that list doesn't seem to be an STL list (`std::list`), if so you should remove the STL tag from your question.

Comment: the info here is relevant for STL containers as well as any custom.

Comment: Well, it's relevant in general to pointers to base classes. Does any question about pointers be tagged as STL? :)